# Images in 'List View' - Hyperlink breaking with odd numbered ID's - Data Mismatch

Tags: asp.net, sql, .net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Having some real issues with this and cannot suss out where the problem lies.

I have created a basic car site which as the ability for users to upload pictures. i got a detail page, that hyperlink according the unique ID, which works fine. It all breaks down when i inserted a list view into the equation. I essentially want to make a small gallery, where a user clicks on it and it shows specific details.

It does work, however, if you refer to the image, this is what happens:[image]

Now the images that work do not link at all to its unique ID (says data mismatch). The images that don't work link perfectly fine to its unique ID, but fails to display pictures.

cardata.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="cardata.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.cardata" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
<br />
<br />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="TagsDataSource" Height="23px" Width="130px" CellPadding="4" style="color: #663300" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Tag" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="CarByTags.aspx?Tag={0}" DataTextField="Tag" />
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#284775" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="TagsDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CarDataString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CarDataString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Tag] FROM [tags]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GroupItemCount="3">
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <td runat="server" style="background-color:#FFF8DC;">
            <asp:Label ID="Image" runat="server"  />
            <a href='cardetail.aspx?ID={0}' />
            <img src='<%# Eval("Image") %>' height="230" width="400" />
                </a>
            <br />
        </td>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <td runat="server" style="background-color:#008A8C;color: #FFFFFF;">Image:
            <asp:TextBox ID="ImageTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Image") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            <br /></td>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <table runat="server" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;">
            <tr>
                <td>No data was returned.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <EmptyItemTemplate>
<td runat="server" />
    </EmptyItemTemplate>
    <GroupTemplate>
        <tr id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
            <td id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></td>
        </tr>
    </GroupTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <td runat="server" style="">Image:
            <asp:TextBox ID="ImageTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Image") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
            <br /></td>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td runat="server" style="background-color:#DCDCDC;color: #000000;">Image:
            <asp:Label ID="ImageLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Image") %>' />
            <asp:HyperLink ID="hlEdit" runat="server" 
            NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "cardetail.aspx?ID={0}")%>'
  ImageUrl="~/Images/edit.png"></asp:HyperLink>
            <br /></td>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table runat="server">
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server">
                    <table id="groupPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="1" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                        <tr id="groupPlaceholder" runat="server">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server" style="text-align: center;background-color: #CCCCCC;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #000000;">
                    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PageSize="12">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowLastPageButton="True" />
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DataPager>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <SelectedItemTemplate>
        <td runat="server" style="background-color:#008A8C;font-weight: bold;color: #FFFFFF;">Image:
            <asp:Label ID="ImageLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Image") %>' />
            <asp:HyperLink ID="hlEdit" runat="server" 
            NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "cardetail.aspx?ID={0}")%>'
  ImageUrl="~/Images/edit.png"></asp:HyperLink>
            <br /></td>
    </SelectedItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CarDataString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CarDataString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Image] FROM [carclub]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<br />
<br />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Car Make" HeaderText="Car Make" SortExpression="Car Make" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Model" HeaderText="Model" SortExpression="Model" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="Age" SortExpression="Age" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Engine Size" HeaderText="Engine Size" SortExpression="Engine Size" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Origin" HeaderText="Origin" SortExpression="Origin" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="BHP" HeaderText="BHP" SortExpression="BHP" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Layout" HeaderText="Layout" SortExpression="Layout" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="cardetail.aspx?ID={0}" HeaderText="More Details" Text="Details" />
</Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#284775" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CarDataString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CarDataString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [carclub]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

cardetail.aspx

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class cardetail
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If IsPostBack = False Then
        If Request.Params("ID") = "" Then Response.Redirect("cardata.aspx")
        Dim oleDbConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CarDataString").ConnectionString)
        Dim SqlString As String = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE car_fkId=@f1"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(SqlString, oleDbConn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", Request.Params("ID"))
        oleDbConn.Open()
        Dim dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        GridView2.DataSource = dataReader
        GridView2.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub btn_AddComment_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_AddComment.Click
    Dim oleDbConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CarDataString").ConnectionString)
    Dim SqlString As String = "Insert into comments(Author, Comment, Title, car_fkId) Values (@f1,@f2,@f3,@f4)"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(SqlString, oleDbConn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", tb_author.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f2", tb_title.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f3", tb_comment.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f4", Request.Params("ID"))
    oleDbConn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    ''''''fill Gridview2
    Dim fillComments As String = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE car_fkId=@f1"
    Dim fillCommentsCmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(fillComments, oleDbConn)
    fillCommentsCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    fillCommentsCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", Request.Params("ID"))
    Dim dataReader = fillCommentsCmd.ExecuteReader()
    GridView2.DataSource = dataReader
    GridView2.DataBind()
    tb_author.Text = ""
    tb_comment.Text = ""
    tb_title.Text = ""



End Sub

Protected Sub CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBoxList1.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim oleDbConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CarDataString").ConnectionString)
    Dim SqlString As String = "INSERT INTO CarTagJunction(Car_fkId,Tag_fkId) VALUES(@f1,@f2)"
    oleDbConn.Open()
    For Each cb As ListItem In CheckBoxList1.Items
        If cb.Selected Then
            'here is where we add the join to the table of tags of cars

            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(SqlString, oleDbConn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", Request.Params("ID"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f2", cb.Value)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End If
    Next
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then Return
    Dim newTags = TextBox1.Text.Split(",")
    For Each newTag In newTags
        Dim newTagSql As String = "INSERT INTO Tags(Tag) VALUES(@f1)"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(newTagSql, oleDbConn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", newTag)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Dim getLastIdCmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT TOP 1 ID from Tags ORDER BY ID DESC", oleDbConn)
        Dim dr = getLastIdCmd.ExecuteReader()
        dr.Read()
        Dim LastId = dr.GetValue(0)

        Dim newcmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(SqlString, oleDbConn)
        newcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        newcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", Request.Params("ID"))
        newcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f2", LastId)
        newcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Next

End Sub

Protected Sub LoginView1_ViewChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginView1.ViewChanged

End Sub

Protected Sub tb_author_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tb_author.TextChanged

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your anchor tag has several issues:

1. The tag is closed early. Then there is a closed `</a>` without any
   opening `<a>`.
2. `href` is incorrect, `ID={0}` will cause an error when you will try to
   convert it to int.
3. `<img>` has no relation with the preceding <`a>` tag.

Your markup should be like this:

```
<AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <td runat="server" style="background-color:#FFF8DC;">
        <asp:Label ID="Image" runat="server"  />
        <a href='<%# Eval("ID", "cardetail.aspx?ID={0}") %>' >
            <img src='<%# Eval("Image") %>' height="230" width="400" />
        </a>
        <br />
    </td>
</AlternatingItemTemplate>
```

After fixing this, if you still have issues, try to debug image url's and href's using client side debugging tool and update your question.

Comment: This worked best for me. I copied this and the links started working however pictures were blank. Thanks to asm00, he mentioned the 2 templates which i copied the code into, and it now works flawlessly. Honestly hope one day i can be knowledgable like you guys in asp.net (student and all :P) thanks for all your help guys!!

Answer (score 1):

First, you tagged this as `asp.net-mvc3` but the problem has nothing to do to MVC, it seems you are using `Web Forms`.

I believe that the root of your 2 problems lie within the 2 different templates that you are using for odd and even items in the ListView.

Odd items will render according to this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <td runat="server" style="background-color:#DCDCDC;color: #000000;">Image:
        <asp:Label ID="ImageLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Image") %>' />
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hlEdit" runat="server" 
        NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "cardetail.aspx?ID={0}")%>'
        ImageUrl="~/Images/edit.png"></asp:HyperLink>
        <br />
    </td>
</ItemTemplate>
```

And even items according this:

```
<AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <td runat="server" style="background-color:#FFF8DC;">
        <asp:Label ID="Image" runat="server"  />
        <a href='cardetail.aspx?ID={0}' />
        <img src='<%# Eval("Image") %>' height="230" width="400" />
            </a>
        <br />
    </td>
</AlternatingItemTemplate>
```

So, now to your problems:

**Odd items won't display the image:**

It looks like you are using the wrong path to your images in the `ItemTemplate`. Try changing your `HyperLink` like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlEdit" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "cardetail.aspx?ID={0}")%>' ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Image") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

**Hyperlink won't work for even items:**

Two things looks wrong here. First, you marked your anchor as singleton (closed the tag like this `/>`).
Apart from that, you are not properly replacing `{0}` with the databound item's id.
Try changing your anchor tag within `AlternatingItemTemplate` like this:

```
<a href='<%# Eval("ID", "cardetail.aspx?ID={0}")%>' >
```

NOTE: Try to keep it simple and avoid re-inventing the wheel. If you already have a `ItemTemplate` that works, copy it to the `AlternatingItemTemplate` and modify the elements that need to be changed. You'll realize that more often than none, you don't even need to use the alternate template...